# Plug.Parser not reading/parsing JSON body

Tags: elixir, plug

I am coding an Elixir (1.8) + Plug_Cowboy (2.0.2) + Jason (1.1.2) server. From what I am getting from the documentation, once the Plug parser has passed, I should have everything in `body_params`. The problem is that accessing `conn.body_params` in my case returns `%Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :body_params}`. Check the code below:

```elixir
defmodule Test.Router do
  use Plug.Router
  require Logger

  plug :match
  plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json],
                     pass: ["application/json", "text/json"],
                     json_decoder: Jason
  plug :dispatch

  post "/test" do
    Logger.debug inspect(conn.body_params)
    conn
      |> put_resp_content_type("text/plain")
      |> send_resp(204, "Got it")
    end
end
```

Any idea what is going on?

I test this with:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: text/json" -d "{one: 1, two: 2}" 127.0.0.1:8080/test
```

I have tried adding `:urlencoded` to parsers, or rearranging the plug order, but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Plug.Parsers.JSON`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.JSON.html) only handles the `application/json` content type. This is the reason the `body_params` is not being populated. Your test JSON is also invalid - the object property names were not quoted.

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"one": 1, "two": 2}' 127.0.0.1:8080/test
```

The [`pass:`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Parsers.html#module-options) option to `Plug.Parsers` instructs it to ignore requests of those types for which there is no parser defined (such as `text/json` in your case), rather than raise an `UnsupportedMediaTypeError`, which is what it would usually do. Adding that option was hiding the error.

You might find it useful to `use`[`Plug.Debugger`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Debugger.html) during development - it will give you better information of what is happening in unexpected situations.

If for some reason you need to be able to parse JSON with the non-standard `text/json` type (because of requests from software you cannot control, for example), you can define a new parser for that type that just wraps up `Plug.Parsers.JSON` and rewrites `text/json` to `application/json`:

```elixir
defmodule WrongJson do
  def init(opts), do: Plug.Parsers.JSON.init(opts)

  def parse(conn, "text", "json", params, opts) do
    Plug.Parsers.JSON.parse(conn, "application", "json", params, opts)
  end

  def parse(conn, _type, _subtype, _params, _opts), do: {:next, conn}
end
```

Then add it to your list of parsers:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers,
  parsers: [:json, WrongJson],
  json_decoder: Jason
```

Now `text/json` will also work.

Comment: Thank you for the priceless information for both Plug.Debug and the application/json only handling. The "test" JSON was actually a mistake during question writing - I "obfuscated" my real request 